# Volume Button long press event

Tags: android

I want to make a toast message when the Volume Up button is pressed for a Specific time.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
    if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP){
        event.startTracking();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode,event);
}
@Override
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode,KeyEvent event){
    if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Volume Up Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
    return onKeyLongPress(keyCode,event);
} }
```

Here it's making a toast message on long press But I want to toast it when the button is presses for 5 sec, How can i give a specific time duration for that !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare global count variable: `int count = 0` and `int key, keyEvent;`

Add this in your key down press method

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
 if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP){
     key = keyCode;
     keyEvent = KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP;
    new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {

public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    if(key==keyEvent){
      count++; 
    }
     else{
      count = 0;
     }  
}
public void onFinish() {
    if(count = 5){
      //Notify Them it's been 5 seconds
      }
     count = 0;
 }
}.start();
    return true;
  }
 return super.onKeyDown(keyCode,event);
}
```

Comment: It's not working, Can you update your answer with my actual code !

Comment: You said it's not working. Be specific of what's not working. You should be able to figure out what's wrong with the code.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code ! the issue may be with the way how i implemented it with my code ! can you update your answer along with my code ?

Comment: I didn't test this but If it doesn't work it should lead you on to the right track. Check my edited answer.

Comment: This doesn't check if the key is still pressed though, it just waits 5s.